# How to fit cubic equation on pybrain

Tags: python, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, pybrain

I am trying to fit a Neural Network on a cubic Equation, but after many tries changing the number of the neurons on the hidden layer and increasing the number of epochs I could only get this: 
[image]

Could you guys help me on this?

```
from pybrain.datasets import SupervisedDataSet
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.structure import TanhLayer
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#Preparing Data
dataset = pd.read_csv("C:\Users\gugub\Documents\projects\Cyrus\graph.data", header = None)
darray = np.array(dataset)
x = []
y = []
ds = SupervisedDataSet(1,1)
#Preparing True inputs and True Outputs
for i in range(43):
    e1 = darray[i,0]
    s1 = darray[i,1]
    x.append(e1)
    y.append(s1)
print(x)
print(y)
ds = SupervisedDataSet(1,1)

i = 0
for i in range(43):
    ds.addSample(x[i],y[i])
print(ds)
net = buildNetwork(ds.indim,30,ds.outdim,recurrent=True)
trainer = BackpropTrainer(net,learningrate=0.01,verbose=True)

trainer.trainOnDataset(ds,20000)
trainer.testOnData(verbose=True)

y1 = []

i = 0
for i in x:
    y1.append(net.activate(i))

plt.plot(x,y,'r')
plt.plot(x,y1,'b')
plt.show()

while True:
    e2 = int(raw_input(">"))
    s2 = [e2]
    print(net.activate(s2))
```

P.S The red line on the graph is what it should be and the blue one is the function generated by my network

Comment: write formula of your cubic function